# jQuery .hover bug

Tags: jquery

im doing some code to do something when mouse is over the box ("titulo") but when the mouse is over the letter the effect turn off. the code is above and the site is here:

http://www.feijaodesign.com/toga/

the box with the effect is the only with the text "PROMOÇOES"

thanks mates.

```
$(".titulo").hover(function(){
  $(".titulo").animate({
    top: "0px",
    height: "100px"
  }, 100 );
});

$(".titulo").hover(function(){
  $(".titulo").animate({
    top: "55px",
    height: "45px"
  }, 100 );
});
```

Comment: Please, don't assume any problem you meet while developing is a bug in the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method in a different way:

```
$(".titulo").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: "0px",
        height: "100px"
    }, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: "55px",
        height: "45px"
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: nice! it works! just one more question. if i want to do the same effect when the mouse is over the letters too, what i have to do? the same code but for the letters ?

Comment: @user1928829 You have `div` with ID `content` overlapping your `.titulo` elements. Change your markup and the effect will work as you wish.